# Common algorithm/hash for VB.net and PHP using mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net, hash

I am working on a projects for VB.net(windows form application) and PHP(website). These two different application is linked to a single database. The database happened to have a users account. That is why I have username, password and other sensitive information of the user. I would like to hash/encrypt the data in my mySQL database. I have some questions or looking for suggestions:

1. What algo/hash is common for VB.net and php where in the hashed string in VB.net should be the same in PHP?

I am doing my own researches, I managed to use MD5+Salt, but the community says it is not good hash. So I search more and found SHA256 and SHA512. If this algo is used with a salt. The security is higher.

2. If i will use salt, how can I generate a salt in VB.net and PHP with the same length?

I read from others that the length of the salt should/must be the same as the other hashed columns. Also, they said that the salt value should be saved in a table together with others. I also want to know since I have a salt. Can I use that salt I used in password to hash the email, firstname, lastname of the users?

3. I also searched about bcrypt in PHP. Is there a bcrypt in VB.net?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Comment: Is there a bcrypt equivalent in VB.net?

Comment: Pick one, either PHP or VB.net to access the database. Then the other one accesses the DB by calling the it. You really do not want to create two sets of DB access programs, twice as many chances of errors.. The most important thing is to properly secure the user's passwords.

Comment: PHP password_hash/password_verify are the easiest to use and get right.

Comment: So there is no bcrypt equivalent in VB.net? I cant pick one. The required is Vb.net and PHP at the same time.

Comment: If you can't provide security have the guts to stop now. It is completely wrong and unethical to put the users at risk because a developer can not provide secure code. Users are put at risk for other sites they may used the same password and it will never know this site has been successfully attacked. Perhaps Bruce Schneier is correct that we need government regulations (see this month's [Crypto-Gram](https://www.schneier.com/crypto-gram/archives/2017/0215.html#1)).

Comment: @zaph your comment now is totally off =(